# Change view when facebook login is done

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm integrating a Facebook log in in my iOs application using the Facebook SDK. Is there a way to change the view the facebook log in button takes me back to once the user logged in ? Right now it takes me back to the view where the FBLoginView was clicked.

To schematize:

Right now I have: View1 -> FacebookView -> View1

What I want:      View1 -> FacebookView -> View2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, when you call openActiveSession... on FBSession, call h handler method in the completionHandler block. Something like this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error]];
                                     }];
```

in this handler you can do things after facebook returns depending on the status. Something like this:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                        state:(FBSessionState)state
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            // login successful
            // do something - like push to another view controller
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // show an error prompt or something
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Check out the facebook docs and also the examples. A lot of this is lifted directly from their examples.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i can unfortunately only access to a mac next friday, i keep you informed when a can try your solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i saw this in the documentation but my auto-completion didn't sugest this method, i thought i didn't had it on my version of the sdk.

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. `FBSession` is deprecated in the most recent sdk.